# An Erlang guard sequence which checks if a term is a list of length == n

Tags: erlang, guard

Is it possible to put a guard sequence that would check both term type and its length? I read that the first passing guard makes the whole sequence pass, so I suppose when I check for the term to be a list, it doesn't check the rest guards.
Here is the code:

```
save_key(Key)
    when
      is_list(Key);
      length(Key) == 44 ->

    ok.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to combine guard expressions with `and`, you can separate them with a comma instead of semicolon as mentioned [here](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id84459):

```
-module(a).
-export([save_key/1]).

save_key(Key)
    when
      is_list(Key),
      length(Key) == 44 ->
    ok;
save_key(_) ->
    ko.
```

```
1> c(a).
{ok,a}
2> a:save_key([]).
ko
3> a:save_key(nil).
ko
4> a:save_key(lists:seq(1, 44)).
ok
```

Also note that since errors thrown in guards are ignored, you can just add the `length(Key) == 44` and get the same behavior as a non-list will throw an error and will not match that clause:

```
save_key(Key) when length(Key) == 44 ->
    ok;
save_key(_) ->
    ko.
```

Comment: Thanks, bud, it's just what I need!